# Solving a non-linear ODE system with ParametricNDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, parametric-functions

I'm trying to solve a non linear ODE numerically with `ParametricNDSolve`, but as far as I got is shown below. My problem is to set the find root correctly.
What I know is this: `x'[0] == 0, x[R] == 0, x'[R] == 0`.
Any help? 
Here is my code:

```
c = -0.7177;
r1 = 0.8;
r2 = 125;
R = 1.39;
f[r_] := Piecewise[{{0, 0 <= r <= r1}, {900/(1 - r1^3), 
    r1 < r <= 1}, {0, 1 < r <= R}}]


ps = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x''[r] + (1/r) x'[r] == 
    c n Exp[-x[r]] + f[r], x'[0] == 0, x[0] == x0}, {x, x'}, {r, 0, 
   R}, {x0,n}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]

ff = FindRoot[{Last[ps[x0,n]][R] == 0, First[ps[x0,n]][R] == 0}, {x0, -2}]
```

Comment: How do you want to combine these three solutions of three different equations? Or is this one solution of an equation with discontinuous coefficients?

Comment: It is one equations has three regions see the image.

Comment: And why in conditions $R<b$

Comment: it is R>b. I fixed it

Answer (score 9):

This problem has a solution. It is given below

```
c = 0.72;
    h = 300;
    a = 15;
    b = 17;
    R = 25;
    f[r_] := Piecewise[{{0, 0 <= r <= a}, {(3 h)/(a^3 - b^3), 
        a < r <= b}, {0, b < r <= R}}]


ps = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x''[r] + 2 x'[r] == 
     c n0 Exp[-x[r]] + f[r], x'[0] == 0, x[0] == x0}, 
   x, {r, 0, R}, {n0, x0}];

 n = 
 FindRoot[{ps[n0, x0][R] == 0, ps[n0, x0]'[R] == 0}, {n0, -.2}, {x0, 
   1}]

 {n0 -> 9.19855*10^-8, x0 -> 0.585175}

{Plot[
 Evaluate[Table[ps[n0, 1][r], {n0, -.2, 2, .1}]], {r, 0, R}, 
 PlotRange -> All],
 Plot[ps[n[[1, 2]], n[[2, 2]]][r], {r, 0, R}]}
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Ah, now I get it. The third boundary condition is used to determine the parameter `n0`. Good job (and of course +1)!

Answer (score 4):

As Alex Trounev said, this is a second-order ODE with discontinuous right-hand side. You can use `Piecewise` to set up the forcing term:

```
rhs = Piecewise[{
  {c n0 Exp[-x[r]] + (3 h)/(a^3 - b^3), a <= r < b}
  },
 c n0 Exp[-x[r]]
 ]
```

> $$\begin{cases}  \frac{3 h}{a^3-b^3}+c \,\text{n0}\, e^{-x(r)} & a\leq r<b \\  c \,\text{n0} \, e^{-x(r)} & \text{True} \end{cases}$$

Notice that for convenience, I used `c n0 Exp[-x[r]]` as the default term. The full equation can be set up as

```
c = 0.72;
h = 300;
a = 15;
b = 17;
R = 25;
ϵ = $MachineEpsilon;

ps = ParametricNDSolveValue[
   {
    x''[r] + 2 x'[r] == rhs,
    x[R] == 0,
    x'[R] == 0
    },
   x,
   {r, ϵ, R},
   {n0},
   Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", WorkingPrecision -> 30
   ];
```

Solving it for a given parameter

```
f = ps[0.00001];
```

Plotting the result:

```
Plot[f[r], {r, ϵ, R}]
```

[image]

Something must be wrong in your model: The solution blows up heavily towards $r = 0$ so that `x'[0] == 0` cannot be expected. Actually, you cannot prescribe more than two boundary conditions for an ODE of order 2.

Comment: "Actually, you cannot prescribe more than two boundary conditions for an ODE of order 2." - I'm actually surprised at how frequently people don't remember to check that the number of their conditions matches the order of their ODE...

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher  Look at the solution from the other side at x=0

Comment: @AlexTrounev please see my update in the code.

Comment: @user60416 What is the point of updating the code if the problem has already been solved? Do you want to solve a problem for other data?

Comment: in my update the integral is from a to 1 and yours from a to b, however, I just want to understand how to get the find rood right in my above code. And using different data the problem becomes stiff. How to deal with this?

Comment: @user60416 It is indeed not fair to invalidate already given answers by changing the question.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I'm not invalidate given answer, I just update the data and changed the integral interval. Indeed I used it see above code.

Comment: @user60416 You can ask a new question, and leave this one unchanged.